# Why is my dictionary access so slow?

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I'm running some calculations on a CSV file. Can anyone help me explain why method 1 is about 3 times faster than method 2? I wanted to make my code more generic and sustainable so I didn't want to hardcode like in method 1, but the performance has dropped drastically once I switched to method 2 and I can't figure out why.

Method 1:

```
for row in itertools.islice(csv_f, 0, period):
    voltage_rail1 = float(row[rail1_index])
    voltage_rail1_q.append(voltage_rail1)
    current_rail1 = float(row[current_index])
    current_rail1_q.append(current_rail1)
    power_rail1_q.append(voltage_rail1*current_rail1)

    voltage_rail2 = float(row[rail2_index])
    voltage_rail2_q.append(voltage_rail2)
    current_rail2 = float(row[current_index])
    current_rail2_q.append(current_rail2)
    power_rail2_q.append(voltage_rail2*current_rail2)
```

Method 2:

```
rails_d = OrderedDict()
rails_d['rail1'] = 0
rails_d['rail2'] = 1

for row in itertools.islice(csv_f, 0, period):
    for rail in rails_d:
        voltage_d[rail] = float(row[voltage_column_index_d[rail]])
        voltage_dq[rail].append(voltage_d[rail])
        current_d[rail] = float(row[current_column_index_d[rail]])
        current_dq[rail].append(current_d[rail])
        power_dq[rail].append(voltage_d[rail]*current_d[rail])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a dictionary? From both snippets, it looks like you're using only the key (or the index 0/1) Maybe a list will speed things up a bit

```
for rail in ['rail1','rail2']:
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12543900/2599266) discusses iteration performance in-depth.

Side-note, have you tried [product](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) from itertools

```
for rail, row in itertools.product(['rail1','rail2'], itertools.islice(csv_f, 0, period)):
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I've implemented both but the performance looks to be about the same.

`rails_l = ['rail1', 'rail2']
for rail, row in itertools.product(rails_l, itertools.islice(csv_f, 0, period)):
    voltage_d[rail] = float(row[voltage_column_index_d[rail]])
    voltage_dq[rail].append(voltage_d[rail])
    current_d[rail] = float(row[current_column_index_d[rail]])
    current_dq[rail].append(current_d[rail])
    power_dq[rail].append(voltage_d[rail]*current_d[rail])`